# How to check if Firebase Query Returns more than 1 Record?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

It seems firebase Query doesn't have methods for returned records count. but, I need to perform some data operation based on returned records.

```
var queryRef=database.child("Family").orderByChild("age").limitToFirst(10)

queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener 
{
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
           if(p0.exists()){
             // do something
         }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
    }

})
```

but, similarly, I want p0.resultsCount instead of p0.exists(). Help, me If any way it is possible to figure out returned records count.

Comment: in `onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) { if (DataSnapshot.exists() && DataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 1) }`

Comment: @ÖzerÖzcan While there are many good reasons to consider Cloud Firestore over the Realtime Database, neither of them support count queries like Jay is asking. In fact, for the purpose of this question they work pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of children to which a Firebase Reference is pointing using the below method.

```
getChildrenCount()
```

For you it would be `p0.getChildrenCount()`

Comment: No, I don't want children's count. I just want records count requested for firebase query.

Comment: @JayMungara Since you are limiting to 10, the number of records is also equal to 10.

Comment: if there are total 5 records then how many results will it provide me?

Comment: @JayMungara In that case, getChildrenCount() would be useful and you will get the answer 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can check number of children  by using this method.

```
dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
```

Or you can convert your datasnapshot into hashmap to check number of Nodes from query and then check it's size.

```
HashMap hashMapAccounts = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
hashMapAccounts.size();
```

Comment: Read Question Carefully about requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can get count by

```
var queryRef=database.child("Family").orderByChild("age").limitToFirst(10)

queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener 
{
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
           if(p0.exists()){
             // do something
             val count:Int? = p0.childrenCount
           }
    }

override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
}

});
```